# PGP decryption using java api

Tags: java, pgp

i am trying to decrypt a PGP encrypted file. I would like to use the available java api and not third party. Is this possbile? I see posts that java api has capablities wanted to know if some one tried it and have any example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no JDK API for doing this AFAIK, you have to go third party. BouncyCastle would be a good choice to go with.

Comment: Thanks, I would consider using BouncyCastle.

Answer (score 0):

Most pgp java code i've seen uses [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html).  what posts have you seen indicating that java has builtin pgp support?

Comment: Refer link below, seems pretty old though http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=705915

Comment: @user1134904 - all those comments seem to refer to thirdparty libraries